# Angular UI-Grid 3.0.0-rc.16: Pagination not working for me

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-grid

I have a very simple grid and am trying to enable pagination, but paging controls do not appear. Here's what I have:

I have added 'ui.grid.pagination' as a dependency on my app module.

html:

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-pagination external-scopes="$scope" class="campaigns-grid"></div>
```

js:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'campaigns',
  enableRowSelection: true,
  noUnselect: true,
  enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
  multiSelect: false,
  enablePaginationControls: true,
  paginationPageSize: 5,
  paginationPageSizes: [5, 10, 15],
  rowTemplate: '<div ng-dblclick="getExternalScopes().onDblClickRow(row)" ng-click="grid.appScope.fnOne(row)" ng-repeat="col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ui-grid-cell></div>',
  columnDefs: [
    { field: 'name', displayName: 'Name' },
    { 
      name: 'delete', 
      displayName: 'Delete', 
      enableCellEdit: false, 
      width: 200,
      cellTemplate: '<a href ng-click="getExternalScopes().deleteCampaign(row.entity)"><i class="fa fa-trash deleteButton"></i></a>' 
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pagination is not available in the RC 16, you should use the latest unstable version.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/2479

**EDIT:**

As a unstable I don't think is included as an available version, in fact when running `bower info angular-ui-grid` , I see:

> Available versions:
>
> - 3.0.0-rc.16
> - 3.0.0-rc.15
> - 3.0.0-rc.14
> - 3.0.0-rc.13
> - 3.0.0-rc.12
> - 3.0.0-rc.11
> - 3.0.0-rc.10
> - 3.0.0-rc.8
> - 3.0.0-rc.7
> - 3.0.0-RC.18

So it is not possible to install the unstable version via bower, either download the files or include them from the host: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid#how-can-i-test-30

Comment: How can we bower install the unstable version?

Answer (score 0):

module = angular.module('app',
        ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.autoResize', 'ui.grid.pagination', 'ui.grid.grouping', 'ui.grid.cellNav', 'ui.grid.moveColumns', 'ui.grid.exporter', 'ui.grid.pinning', 'ui.grid.resizeColumns', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.autoFitColumns', 'angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);

```
module.controller("SalesOrder",
    ['$scope', '$filter', '$timeout', '$http', '$interval', 'uiGridConstants', 'uiGridGroupingConstants', '$q',
        function ($scope, $filter, $timeout, $http, $q, uiGridConstants, uiGridGroupingConstants, $interval, $window) {
```